# ¿Cómo agrego un gif a un mensaje en discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

Quiero hacer comandos de interacción en mi bot que creé en `discord.py`, que se parezca a los comandos del `bot chocolat`, para eso necesito agregar un *gif* a un `embed` y no se como hacerlo, estuve viendo la documentación de `discord.py` pero no encontré nada para agregar un *gif*, estoy iniciando en `python` y solo sé programar respuestas de esta manera:

```
@bot.command(name="ping")
async def ping(ctx):
     await ctx.send(f'{ctx.message.author.mention}, pong!')
```

Así que si alguien sabe una forma fácil de hacer esto por favor responda.

Answer (score 1):

En la línea `embed.set_image()` cambia `url.gif` por el enlace de tu gif:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@client.command()
async def nombre_comando(ctx):

    embed = discord.Embed(
        colour=discord.Colour.teal(),
        title="Título del embed",
        description="Descripción del embed"
    )
    embed.set_image(url="url.gif")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/201235)

Comment: A ok, perdon, no vi lo del embed pero mira es asi, ya edite mi respuesta